# How to extract urdu text from image in c#?

Tags: c#, image, c#-4.0

i have wrote a code which extracts text from any image and works correctly but only for English, i want make it workable from URDU too i.e. extracting URDU text from image.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MODI;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        string extractText = this.ExtractTextFromImage(filePath);
        lblText.Text = extractText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
    }

    private string ExtractTextFromImage(string filePath)
    {
        Document modiDocument = new Document();
        modiDocument.Create(filePath);
        modiDocument.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH);
        MODI.Image modiImage = (modiDocument.Images[0] as MODI.Image);
        string extractedText = modiImage.Layout.Text;
        modiDocument.Close();
        return extractedText;
    }

}
```

Comment: What OCR languages have you selected when you installed Office?

Comment: English , i selected english

Comment: Then Office will only OCR English text.  This isn't magic, the computer does exactly what it is configured to do.

Comment: any other way to solve it